# Turn off debug logs on Camel

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-camel

I am trying to turn off debug logs. I followed the following steps 
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-enable-debug-logging.html

I made log level `INFO`, but still can see debug logs. I tried to create `log4j.xml` instead of `log4j.properties`, same issue. It doesn't seem that my configuration being picked up at all.

Update:

log file: log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out 
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=INFO

log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=[%30.30t] %-30.30c{1} %-5p
```

Comment: Do you run your program as a standalone app, or do you use some container?

Comment: share your log4j.properties config.

Comment: I added it to the original post

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem of being unable to configure log4j while using Camel. It was caused by the fact that there were several slf4j bindings in the classpath, and in my case slf4j chose logback over log4j.

If you encounter this issue, look for these around the beginning of the log:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

The quick & dirty way to solve the problem is to create a configuration file for every potential bindings found. The clean way is to find what dependency imports the unwanted binding; and configure your dependency manager so that only the binding of your choosing is bundled with your app.

See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for more details.